# Redeploy of an web application on weblogic not desroying the old objects

Tags: java, spring, performance, weblogic, weblogic12c

Steps: -

1. Delete the existing application war using admin console on weblogic.
2. Install the new war.
3. Take & check the yourKit memory snapshot.
4. The new object count is just double the existing ones.

Please let me know if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Have you used jconsole to check as well? It may take some time for it all to get garbage collected. And is it causing problems? We hot deploy ears/wars all the time and haven't run into a problem

Comment: It is not causing problems but even after doing force GC the objects are still existing. The spring ApplicationContext itself doesn't get garbage collected.